# Finding for which value of an unknown a linear system has a single solution

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have a system of linear equations (two equations, two variables) and an unknown coefficient `a`. I need to find which values of `a` make the system of equations have a single solution. These are the equations:

```
ax + 2y = 5
8x + ay = 10
```

My general approach for this is to isolate both x and y separately after eliminating one and adding the equations together and to then look if `a` is in any of the denominators which could cause a null division. I'm having trouble finding a way to eliminate the x or y variable, so when I add the equations together and isolate x or y, the other variable always ends up on the other side and I get wrong answers (checked through graphing the equations). Is there any way I can isolate x or y and then isolate them to find out where `a` ends up? Thanks in advance!

For example: After adding the equations together (can't eliminate any variables), I get $x(8+a) + y(2+a) = 15$. Then I can isolate x or y to get for example $$x = \frac{15 - y(2+a)}{(8+a)}$$I believe it's wrong to conclude from that step that `a` cannot have the value -8.

Solution (using @Emilio Novate's method):

After doing the multiplications I isolated x to get:
$$x=\frac{5(a-4)}{a^2-16}$$ While 4 works for a, -4 doesn't!
Now the same for y. I had to multiply the first equation by -8 and the second by a. After eliminating x, I got $$y = \frac{10a-40}{(a^2-16)}$$ This confirms that the value of -4 for a does not work :)

A value of 4 for a will make both the x and y equations evaluate to 0/0. What is the significance of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint for your method:

1) Multiply the first equation by $a$

2) multiply the second equation by $-2$

3) sum the two equations and find: $x(a^2-16)=5(a-4)$

4) find for what values of $a$ there is a solution.

Comment: Question: A value of -4 for `a` will make the two lines parallel (no solution), and I found this using your method and seeing that they make the denominator 0 while the numerator is a non-zero number. However, +4 for a will make the equation evaluate to 0/0 for both x and y. When graphing this I saw it made the lines equal (infinite solutions). Is this always the case when the equations evaluate to 0/0. So a value of 4 for a also does not create a single solution?

Comment: Correct: $a=4 \Rightarrow$ infinite solutions .

Answer (score 0):

The system has a unique solution iff $a \times a -2 \times 8 \not =0 \Leftrightarrow a \not = \pm 4$, by the "determinant law".

Comment: Is there no way to figure this out without using the determinant method? My textbook for some reason doesn't ever mention this method even in the slightest in the section on solving linear systems with two variables.